# Integrating SSRS reports into web - Chrome equivalent-JavaScript hack for Opera/FF/IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, cross-browser

I have a problem with the datepicker in Microsoft SSRS reports (generated on a website). The datepicker, by default, doesn't work. So I found this code online ([from 2011 and outdated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGe5q.png)) to get around it:

```
$($(":hidden[id*='DatePickers']").val().split(",")).each(function (i, item) {
    var h = $("table[id*='ParametersGrid'] span").filter(function (i) {
            var v = "[" + $(this).text() + "]";
            return (v != null && v.indexOf(item) >= 0);
        })
        .parent("td").next("td").find("input").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: '/WebSite1_Reporting_Test/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.calendar.gif', 
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
```

But when I view it in Opera/FF/IE , it looks like:

[image]

It shows 3 date icons, of which two work (the middle one is the default bad-one). But in Chrome it looks good!

[image]

I don't have expertise with JS code and I'm lost here - but a coworker said the filter function was probably unnecessary. Any tips are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a coworker, this was figured out:

```
               .parent("td").next("td").find("input").datepicker(
                    {  dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
```

it was a solution by omission. We bound the datepicker on the input boxes. Somehow, in chrome only the input boxes show-up(clickable), but in IE/FF/Op. you see datepicker also, and both datepicker/input boxes are clickabl.